# How can one convert between mtx format and graph format?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

There are various variants of graph coloring, such as when I want to compute [the star chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_coloring) of a graph, *Mathematica* seems not to provide relevant functions.

Fortunately, the software [ColPack](https://github.com/CSCsw/ColPack)   offers this functionality. However, it supports the MTX format. So, the question is:

- **How can I write a graph in MTX format?**

And

- **how can the MTX format be converted into a graph format?**

Of course, I would like to perform these operations in *Mathematica*.

The following is an example (bcsstk01.mtx） in the directory `ColPack-master/Graphs directory` of the source code of ColPack.

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real symmetric
48 48 224
1 1  2.8322685185200e+06
5 1  1.0000000000000e+06
6 1  2.0833333333300e+06
7 1 -3.3333333333300e+03
11 1  1.0000000000000e+06
19 1 -2.8000000000000e+06
25 1 -2.8935185185200e+04
30 1  2.0833333333300e+06
2 2  1.6354475308600e+06
4 2 -2.0000000000000e+06
6 2  5.5555555555500e+06
8 2 -6.6666666666700e+03
10 2 -2.0000000000000e+06
20 2 -3.0864197530900e+04
24 2  5.5555555555500e+06
26 2 -1.5979166666700e+06
3 3  1.7243672839500e+06
4 3 -2.0833333333300e+06
5 3 -2.7777777777800e+06
9 3 -1.6800000000000e+06
21 3 -1.5432098765400e+04
23 3 -2.7777777777800e+06
27 3 -2.8935185185200e+04
28 3 -2.0833333333300e+06
4 4  1.0033333333300e+09
8 4  2.0000000000000e+06
10 4  4.0000000000000e+08
22 4 -3.3333333333300e+06
27 4  2.0833333333300e+06
28 4  1.0000000000000e+08
5 5  1.0675000000000e+09
7 5 -1.0000000000000e+06
11 5  2.0000000000000e+08
21 5  2.7777777777800e+06
23 5  3.3333333333300e+08
29 5 -8.3333333333300e+05
6 6  1.5353333333300e+09
12 6 -2.0000000000000e+06
20 6 -5.5555555555500e+06
24 6  6.6666666666700e+08
25 6 -2.0833333333300e+06
30 6  1.0000000000000e+08
7 7  2.8322685185200e+06
11 7 -1.0000000000000e+06
12 7  2.0833333333300e+06
13 7 -2.8000000000000e+06
31 7 -2.8935185185200e+04
36 7  2.0833333333300e+06
8 8  1.6354475308600e+06
10 8  2.0000000000000e+06
12 8  5.5555555555500e+06
14 8 -3.0864197530900e+04
18 8  5.5555555555500e+06
32 8 -1.5979166666700e+06
9 9  1.7243672839500e+06
10 9 -2.0833333333300e+06
11 9 -2.7777777777800e+06
15 9 -1.5432098765400e+04
17 9 -2.7777777777800e+06
33 9 -2.8935185185200e+04
34 9 -2.0833333333300e+06
10 10  1.0033333333300e+09
16 10 -3.3333333333300e+06
33 10  2.0833333333300e+06
34 10  1.0000000000000e+08
11 11  1.0675000000000e+09
15 11  2.7777777777800e+06
17 11  3.3333333333300e+08
35 11 -8.3333333333300e+05
12 12  1.5353333333300e+09
14 12 -5.5555555555500e+06
18 12  6.6666666666700e+08
31 12 -2.0833333333300e+06
36 12  1.0000000000000e+08
13 13  2.8360994695000e+06
17 13 -2.1492852945100e+06
18 13  2.3591618040200e+06
19 13 -3.3333333333300e+03
23 13 -1.0000000000000e+06
37 13 -2.8935185185200e+04
42 13  2.0833333333300e+06
43 13 -3.8309509817100e+03
47 13 -1.1492852945100e+06
48 13  2.7582847068300e+05
14 14  1.7674107444600e+06
15 14  5.1792213181600e+05
16 14  4.2985705890200e+06
18 14 -5.5555555555500e+06
20 14 -6.6666666666700e+03
22 14  2.0000000000000e+06
38 14 -1.5979166666700e+06
44 14 -1.3196321359900e+05
45 14 -5.1792213181600e+05
46 14  2.2985705890200e+06
15 15  3.8900380684800e+06
16 15 -2.6349902747000e+06
17 15  2.7777777777800e+06
21 15 -1.6800000000000e+06
39 15 -2.8935185185200e+04
40 15 -2.0833333333300e+06
44 15 -5.1792213181600e+05
45 15 -2.1656707845300e+06
46 15 -5.5165694136700e+05
16 16  1.9757206353100e+09
20 16 -2.0000000000000e+06
22 16  4.0000000000000e+08
39 16  2.0833333333300e+06
40 16  1.0000000000000e+08
44 16 -2.2985705890200e+06
45 16  5.5165694136600e+05
46 16  4.8619365099000e+08
17 17  1.5273465154700e+09
18 17 -1.0977973133200e+08
19 17  1.0000000000000e+06
23 17  2.0000000000000e+08
41 17 -8.3333333333300e+05
43 17  1.1492852945100e+06
47 17  2.2972466123600e+08
48 17 -5.5717351077900e+07
18 18  1.5641114371100e+09
24 18 -2.0000000000000e+06
37 18 -2.0833333333300e+06
42 18  1.0000000000000e+08
43 18 -2.7582847068300e+05
47 18 -5.5717351077900e+07
48 18  1.0941196003800e+07
19 19  2.8322685185200e+06
23 19  1.0000000000000e+06
24 19  2.0833333333300e+06
43 19 -2.8935185185200e+04
48 19  2.0833333333300e+06
20 20  1.6354475308600e+06
22 20 -2.0000000000000e+06
24 20 -5.5555555555500e+06
44 20 -1.5979166666700e+06
21 21  1.7243672839500e+06
22 21 -2.0833333333300e+06
23 21  2.7777777777800e+06
45 21 -2.8935185185200e+04
46 21 -2.0833333333300e+06
22 22  1.0033333333300e+09
45 22  2.0833333333300e+06
46 22  1.0000000000000e+08
23 23  1.0675000000000e+09
47 23 -8.3333333333300e+05
24 24  1.5353333333300e+09
43 24 -2.0833333333300e+06
48 24  1.0000000000000e+08
25 25  6.0879629629600e+04
29 25  1.2500000000000e+06
30 25  4.1666666666700e+05
31 25 -4.1666666666700e+03
35 25  1.2500000000000e+06
26 26  3.3729166666700e+06
28 26 -2.5000000000000e+06
32 26 -8.3333333333300e+03
34 26 -2.5000000000000e+06
27 27  2.4117129629600e+06
28 27 -4.1666666666700e+05
33 27 -2.3550000000000e+06
28 28  1.5000000000000e+09
32 28  2.5000000000000e+06
34 28  5.0000000000000e+08
29 29  5.0183333333300e+08
31 29 -1.2500000000000e+06
35 29  2.5000000000000e+08
30 30  5.0250000000000e+08
36 30 -2.5000000000000e+06
31 31  3.9858796296300e+06
35 31 -1.2500000000000e+06
36 31  4.1666666666700e+05
37 31 -3.9250000000000e+06
32 32  3.4114969135800e+06
34 32  2.5000000000000e+06
36 32  6.9444444444400e+06
38 32 -3.8580246913600e+04
42 32  6.9444444444500e+06
33 33  2.4310030864200e+06
34 33 -4.1666666666700e+05
35 33 -3.4722222222200e+06
39 33 -1.9290123456800e+04
41 33 -3.4722222222200e+06
34 34  1.5041666666700e+09
40 34 -4.1666666666700e+06
35 35  1.3351666666700e+09
39 35  3.4722222222200e+06
41 35  4.1666666666700e+08
36 36  2.1691666666700e+09
38 36 -6.9444444444400e+06
42 36  8.3333333333300e+08
37 37  3.9858796296300e+06
41 37 -1.2500000000000e+06
42 37  4.1666666666700e+05
43 37 -4.1666666666700e+03
47 37 -1.2500000000000e+06
38 38  3.4114969135800e+06
40 38  2.5000000000000e+06
42 38 -6.9444444444500e+06
44 38 -8.3333333333300e+03
46 38  2.5000000000000e+06
39 39  2.4310030864200e+06
40 39 -4.1666666666700e+05
41 39  3.4722222222200e+06
45 39 -2.3550000000000e+06
40 40  1.5041666666700e+09
44 40 -2.5000000000000e+06
46 40  5.0000000000000e+08
41 41  1.3351666666700e+09
43 41  1.2500000000000e+06
47 41  2.5000000000000e+08
42 42  2.1691666666700e+09
48 42 -2.5000000000000e+06
43 43  6.4710580611300e+04
47 43  2.3992852945100e+06
48 43  1.4083819598400e+05
44 44  3.5048798802700e+06
45 44  5.1792213181600e+05
46 44 -4.7985705890200e+06
45 45  4.5773837474900e+06
46 45  1.3499027470000e+05
46 46  2.4723873019800e+09
47 47  9.6167984880400e+08
48 47 -1.0977973133200e+08
48 48  5.3127810377500e+08
```

```
./ColPack -f ../../Graphs/bcsstk01.mtx -m STAR
Out: 11
```

But I do not know what the graph in the example is. I don't understand what the very long decimal numbers (like `2.8322685185200e+06`) in the third column in the MTX-file. Will it affect the  imformation of the entire graph?

On the contrary, I would like to compute the star chromatic number of the graph below, and I also don't know how to convert it into the MTX format like the above.

```
G = GridGraph[{2, 2, 2, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: Look up "MTX" in the help. MMA can import and export this format.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you, I knew that "MTX" is supported (sorry, I forgot to mention it in the main text). However, I can only obtain some matrices or matrix plots, rather than graphs. For example, `s = Import["~\\ColPack-master\\Graphs\
\\bcsstk01.mtx", "Graphics"]`

Comment: I do not know MTX well, but I think it is thought for 3D graphics. And a Graph is 2D.

Comment: @DanielHuber Graphs can also be represented as matrices, primarily the adjacency matrices. However, I don't understand what the very long decimal numbers (like `2.8322685185200e+06`) in the third column in the MTX-matrix.

Comment: @creidhne Thanks! I know. I am concerned these numbers in the third column will effect the information of whole graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume we're working with adjacency matrices that you want to import or export in `MTX` format, and the goal is to create an adjacency matrix from a [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html).

The bcsstk01.mtx file isn't an adjacency matrix. Instead, let's look at the graph in your example. We use [`AdjacencyMatrix`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html) to find an adjacency matrix from the graph, and [`VertexChromaticNumber`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/VertexChromaticNumber.html) to find the graph's chromatic number.

```
g = GridGraph[{2, 2, 2, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
amat = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
VertexChromaticNumber[g]
(*2*)
```

Exporting the `amat` to `MTX` is simple as a file, or as a string as an example.

```
ExportString[amat, "MTX"]
```

> %%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate integer symmetric
> %Created with the Wolfram Language : [www.wolfram.com](http://www.wolfram.com)
> 24 24 52
> 2 1 1
> 3 1 1
> 4 2 1
> [snip]
> 24 20 1
> 24 22 1
> 24 23 1

[`FindVertexColoring`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/FindVertexColoring.html) was introduced in v13. Use it to color the graph vertices.

```
FindVertexColoring[g, ColorData[106,"ColorList"]];(*introduced v13*)
Annotate[g,
  {VertexStyle -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> %],
    VertexSize -> .5, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"}]
```

[image: vertex colored graph]

Use [`MatrixPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html) to plot the adjacency matrix.

```
MatrixPlot[amat]
```

[image: plot of adjacency matrix]

---

### Answer for Comment:

> **For graphs, these decimals seem to be considered as 1 (with the first two columns representing vertices, and their adjacency).**

The data in the bcsstk01.mtx file is not an adjacency matrix. We can force the data with [`Unitize`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/Unitize.html) that replaces the decimal values with 1. [`AdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html) makes a graph from `amat`.

```
(*data = Import["bcsstk01.mtx"];*)(*data imported from MTX file*)
amat = Unitize[amat];
MatrixPlot[amat]
g = AdjacencyGraph[amat]
```

[image: adjacency matrix for MTX file]

[image: graph from adjacency matrix]

Comment: Can you see https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html? For graphs, these decimals seem to   be considered as 1 (with the first two columns representing vertices, and their adjacency). Of course, this is my interpretation and may not be correct.

Comment: @licheng I think the code I've added will show how you can use the data from the MTX file as an adjacency matrix.